# Are there any NFT marketplaces that accept non-media or even arbitrary file formats?

Tags: nft

I am curious as to whether there are NFT marketplaces that allow minting tokens for arbitrary file formats say pdfs, text files, etc .

Answer (score 0):

https://mirror.xyz/ is a publishing platform protocol that allows the tokenization (NFT) of essays and writing.